# How to get TeamCity to recognize msbuild compilation errors, using the Rake runner

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, rake

I have a .NET project with a Rake build script. Rake calls msbuild.exe to do the actual compilation. When I configure a TeamCity 5.0 build using the Rake runner, compilation errors are not recognized as such by TC.  When a compilation error occurs:

1. The build **does** abort and is flagged as a failure;
2. The log overview **does not** contain the compilation error message. I have to go to Build Log -> All Messages to see the failure;
3. The compilation failure is **not reported via email**. The {COMPILATION_ERRORS} placeholder in my email notification template is replaced with a blank string.

What do I have to do to get TC to recognize the compilation errors?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer, as shown in [this thread on the TeamCity support forum](http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/message/5252676#5252676), is to tell MSBuild to use a special TeamCity log listener using the "/l" switch:

```
msbuild /l:JetBrains.BuildServer.MSBuildLoggers.MSBuildLogger,<path to dll>
```

The dll ships in the TeamCity agent directory: {agent}/plugins/dotnetplugin/bin/JetBrains.BuildServer.MSBuildLoggers.dll

Comment: The DLL can be found by resolving the `teamcity.dotnet.nunitlauncher.msbuild.task` system property