# How to run msbuild from ant so that I can see msbuild (compilation) errors on teamcity

Tags: ant, msbuild, teamcity, teamcity-7.1

I have I multilanguage project using Java, C#, C++. And I using ant script for building and running test.

Currently, I exec msbuild from ant script and redirect the msbuild output to log files. If build fails on msbuild (.net) compilation errors I should go to Artifacts and look for log file and search error in this file. I want to see all compilation error on overview tab of TeamCity build (both java and .net).

Teamcity has [MSBuild Task for NAnt](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/NAnt) out of the box, but has no support for MSBuild on Ant. Of course I can split all build process in 2 parts: Ant script for Java ant NAnt for .NET, but it's undesirable.

So, what is the best way to get msbuild (compilation) errors on teamcity build page in case of msbuild is called from Ant build script.

Comment: Why don't you use build steps?

Comment: I need one way to run build in command line and on teamcity.

Comment: If multiple build steps are not the option, so do not redirect MsBuild output to file. It should write directly to stdout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer in this topoc: [How to get TeamCity to recognize msbuild compilation errors, using the Rake runner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883753/how-to-get-teamcity-to-recognize-msbuild-compilation-errors-using-the-rake-runn). I need to run msbuild like this:

> msbuild /l:JetBrains.BuildServer.MSBuildLoggers.MSBuildLogger, path to dll